# Injecting dependencies into an IErrorHandler implementation

Tags: wcf, ninject, ierrorhandler

I am implementing `IErrorHandler` in order to centralize all of the error handling for my WCF service in one place.  This works fairly well:

```
public class ServiceErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        // ..Log..
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        // ..Provide fault..
    }

}
```

Now, we're using Ninject to inject dependencies in the rest of the service, and I'd like to do the same here.  Since WCF is constructing the objects based on my configuration, and I don't think I have any hooks into this process, I need to use property injection:

```
    [Inject]
    public ILoggingService Logger { get; set; }
```

However, this never seems to get injected.  I tried using Ninject's MVC extensions to set `ServiceErrorHandler` to allow injection like a filter, but that didn't seem to do the trick.  Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: Do you use the Ninject WCF extension too?

Comment: @DanielMarbach:  I have the WCF extensions, but I don't see anything in them that would help in this situation.  Is there something that that I could use?

Comment: @zimdanen did you solve this problem? The best would be to inject ILogger without IoC, but with pure... Pure DI. Just inject an interface ILogger in your `ServiceErrorHandler`

Comment: @Marshall:  We're using a service locator pattern for it right now.

Comment: @zimdanen thanks for answer. So you just use a global static class in HandleError? (you know it's a kinda anti pattern?)

Comment: @Marshall:  Yep, sure do.  Sometimes practical concerns affect your code.

Answer (score 6):

Late answer, but you can inject dependencies into `IErrorHandler` by creating your custom `ServiceHost`, let's say `TestServiceHost`.

In your `TestServiceHost` you need to do:

1. Implement constructor with `IErrorHandler` parameter.
2. Inside, create a private nested class named `ErrorHandlerBehaviour`*, which needs to implement both `IServiceBehavior` and `IErrorHandler`. It also must have constructor with `IErrorHandler` parameter.
3. Override `OnStarting()` method, where you will add `ErrorHandlerBehaviour` to service behaviours. All behaviours must be added before `base.OnStarting()`.

*the idea came from Juval Lowy's example in book - "Programming WCF Services". More information about Faults and Error extensions you can find there.

Here is the working host console application. I don't use IoC there, just [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/), but you can easily resolve logger with any IoC you want:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;

namespace ConsoleHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logger = new DummyLogger();
            var errorHandler = new TestErrorHandler(logger);

            ServiceHost host = new TestServiceHost(errorHandler, typeof(TestService), new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8002"));
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITestService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Test(int input);
    }

    public class TestService : ITestService
    {
        public string Test(int input)
        {
            throw new Exception("Test exception!");
        }
    }

    public class TestErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
    {
        private ILogger Logger { get; }

        public TestErrorHandler(ILogger logger)
        {
            Logger = logger;
        }

        public bool HandleError(Exception error)
        {
            Logger.Log(error.Message);
            return true;
        }

        public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
        {
            FaultException fe = new FaultException();
            MessageFault message = fe.CreateMessageFault();
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, message, null);
        }
    }

    public class TestServiceHost : ServiceHost
    {
        private readonly IErrorHandler errorHandler;

        public TestServiceHost(IErrorHandler errorHandler, Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
            : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
        {
            this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
        }

        protected override void OnOpening()
        {
            Description.Behaviors.Add(new ErrorHandlerBehaviour(errorHandler));
            base.OnOpening();
        }

        class ErrorHandlerBehaviour : IServiceBehavior, IErrorHandler
        {
            private readonly IErrorHandler errorHandler;

            public ErrorHandlerBehaviour(IErrorHandler errorHandler)
            {
                this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
            }

            bool IErrorHandler.HandleError(Exception error)
            {
                return errorHandler.HandleError(error);
            }

            void IErrorHandler.ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
            {
                errorHandler.ProvideFault(error, version, ref fault);
            }

            void IServiceBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
            {
                foreach (ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
                {
                    channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(this);
                }
            }

            void IServiceBehavior.AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
            {
            }

            void IServiceBehavior.Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    // Dummy logger
    public interface ILogger
    {
        void Log(string input);
    }

    public class DummyLogger : ILogger
    {
        public void Log(string input) => Console.WriteLine(input);
    }
}
```

And configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="ConsoleHost.TestService">
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8002/TestService"
                binding="netTcpBinding"
                contract="ConsoleHost.ITestService" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Btw. Make sure you added `System.Runtime.Serialization` to your references